# GAC contains only a few assemblies after installing Mono on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, mono, .net-assembly

I'm trying to run .NET code which was previously complied on Windows by copying it to Ubuntu Server with Mono installed. I used

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

and it ran fine. Now I run

```
gacutil -l
```

and it outputs only the following assemblies

```
I18N
I18N.West
Mono.Security
System
System.Configuration
System.Security
System.Xml
```

and my code fails to run. I run

```
MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono ./pathTo/MyWindowsExecutable.exe
```

and debug output says it cannot find `System.Core` assembly.

It looks like I didn't run something which installs more assemblies.

How do I get GAC populated with more assemblies (which my code got used to on Windows)?

Comment: You forgot to mention which ubuntu and package version you installed. It should work by default though.

Comment: @Jester I'm not sure how to find this data now. May it be that there's some specific step for having all popular assemblies installed which failed? What would that be?

Comment: mono-complete should depend on various stuff, such as libmono-system-core4.0-cil which should have the dll. You still didn't say version numbers.

Comment: @Jester It was the latest Ubuntu Server 16 image in the gallery. I created another VM with Ubuntu Server 14 image and there the problem doesn't happen. So I guess that's some issue with that specific image.